# how to use adodb recordset for datagridview's navigator?

Tags: .net, vb.net

hy all, I need a help

What I want to do is to use adodb recordset for datagridview's navigator, example : I make a next button with this code:

```
RS.movenext()
textbox1.text = RS.fields(0).value
```

and here is my connection, recordest and datagridview code :

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection()
con.ConnectionString = "xxx"
con.open()

Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset()
RS.open("Select xxx from yyy", con);

Dim dA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim dS As New DataSet()

dA.Fill(dS, RS, "xxx")
DataGridView1.DataSource(dS.Tables(0))
```

The error says that "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed."

Comment: Why do you even use old ADODB Recordset in a .NET app?

Answer (score 1):

You are making a **trendemous mistake** trying to mix legacy ADODB recordset with .NET code! Plus, you won't ever be able to bind a recordset directly to a grid, because like pretty much every data-aware control, it expects an implementation of `IEnumerable` as its data source. Calling `MoveNext` method would not help you navigating through your records at all here.

If you want to build great .NET data-aware applications, you have to learn how binding in .NET works first. Forget anything you remember about how binding worked back in [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6) days, forget about the former [ado](/questions/tagged/ado) library, it simply doesn't apply anymore.

Instead, use [ado.net](/questions/tagged/ado.net) objects to fetch your data and standard .NET binding objects like `DataSet`, entities or actually pretty much anything you like, as long as it's pure .NET objects, to display and manipulate it.

These links from MSDN website will help you get started:

- [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [How to: Bind a DataView Object to a Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: oke, I'll try use that binding object, but is it possible if I re-querry it if I want to add some searches syntax?

Comment: @bagus It all depends on the type of source you'll end up using. If you want a `DataSet` then likely you will simply call a data adapter's `Fill` method. I really suggest you try to find tutorials on Google to help you get started.